# Donald schreit: "Die Palme des Sieges ist unser", Warum "unser"?

Tags: possessive-pronoun

In Carl Barks’ Geschichte *Das harte Naturgesetz* (Ehapa, Barks Library 30, 1997) springt Donald Duck in die Luft und jubelt (bevor ein Nachbar ihn im nächsten Bild leider  mit einem Blumenkohl auf den Kopf schlägt):

> Gloria! Viktoria! die Schlacht ist gewonnen. Die Palme des Sieges ist **unser**

Meine Frage ist einfach: warum *unser* und nicht *unsere?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update

*Ich muss meine (akzeptierte) Antwort revidieren.*

Wir haben es hier mit zwei möglichen Formen zu tun.

1. Die Palme ... ist unser (›unser‹ = Genitiv Plural des Personalpronomens ›[ich](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ich)‹).
2. Die Palme ... ist unsere (›unsere‹ = Nominativ Plural des Possessivpronomens ›[mein](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein)‹).

Bei der ersten Variante handelt es sich um das Verb "sein" mit Genitiv, das "gehören" bedeutet.

Der zweite Satz ist ein possessiver Ausdruck. Possessive Ausdrücke können Nomen ersetzen. Diese Formen werden vor allem in mündlicher Rede (informeller Sprachstil) verwendet.

Somit sind beide Formen grammatikalisch richtig.

Im Satz

> Die Rache ist mein.

ist "mein" eine veralteter Genitiv von "ich".

*Alte Antwort hier:*

---

Gut aufgepasst! Der Satz ist tatsächlich grammatikalisch **nicht korrekt**. Das Verb

```
sein + Possessivpronomen (im Genitiv)
```

bedeutet *"etwas gehört jemandem"*

Zum Beispiel:

> Der Koffer dort ist meiner.

Geschlecht und Numerus des Possessivpronomens richten sich dabei nach jenen des Objekts.

Wahrscheinlich lag der Person, die den Text verfasst hat, die Redewendung *"Der Sieg ist unser"* so sehr im Ohr, dass sie diesen Fehler gemacht hat.

Also, korrekt ist:

> Die Palme des Sieges ist unsere.

Bei "mein" fällt der Fehler wohl mehr auf:

> Gehört dir die Palme? Ja, das ist meine.
>   Gehört euch die Palme? Ja, das ist unsere.

Comment: Ja, "der Sieg ist unser" oder "Der Koffer ist meiner" sind  völlig klare Konstruktionen . Aber hier es " die Palme (...) ist unsere". Ein Adjektiv [unser] wird doch nicht dem Komplement [Sieges] eines Substantives [Palme] angeglichen? Sagst du die "Die Palme des Festivals ist meines" ?

Comment: @Georges Oh ja. Das hatte ich übersehen. Völlig richtig. Es müsste heißen: "Die Palme des Sieges ist unsere" - ich werde meine Antwort  überarbeiten.

Comment: Herzlichsten Dank, splattne : dein Kommentar und deine  überarbeitete Antwort beruhigen mich sehr!

Comment: Aber man sagt auch: "Die Rache ist mein" und nicht "Die Rache ist meine", oder?

Comment: @Phira Ich habe meine Meinung/Antwort geändert. Siehe Update.

Comment: Mit der neuen Version bin ich einverstanden, obwohl ich nicht überzeugt bin, dass in der analogen Phrase "Die Rache ist mein.", mein ein Genetiv ist.

Comment: @Phira ja, "mein" ist ein veralteter Genitiv von "ich". Heute dekliniert man: *ich / meiner / mir / mich*

Answer (score 9):

Interessante Frage! „Der Sieg ist unser“ ist eine feststehende Phrase, ähnlich "victory is ours". Wegen der unübersehbaren Zahl von Zitaten und Abwandlungen dürfte es schwer sein, die Herkunft einzugrenzen.

Der älteste handfeste Beleg, den ich kenne, ist ein Musikstück, genauer ein Militärmarsch der *[Grande Armée](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_Arm%C3%A9e)* mit dem Titel « *La victoire est à nous !* » (zu dessen Herkunft siehe auch [hier](http://musique2rh.free.fr/sources.htm) [französisch], [hier](http://launch.groups.yahoo.com/group/bugle/message/7545) [englisch] und [hier](http://www.napoleon-online.de/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=1234) - beim letztgenannten Link sind die weiterführenden Links auf gustave.club.fr leider defekt).

Zwar finden sich Informationen zur Herkunft der Melodie und des Titels, weiter zurückverfolgen konnte ich die Phrase leider nicht. Deren deutsche und englische Fassung **könnte** schlicht eine möglichst nahe Übersetzung des französischen Originals sein.

EDIT:

In der Regel werden Possesivpronomen flektiert, siehe [den Beitrag von splattne](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/donald-schreit-die-palme-des-sieges-ist-unser-warum-unser/2679#2679). Davon gibt (oder jedenfalls: gab) es aber Ausnahmen. Nachweise finden sich z.B. im [Grimmschen Wörterbuch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=24,1369,75) s.v. „unser“, unter B.II.; weitere Beispiele bei [Heyse, Theoretisch-praktische deutsche Grammatik, 1849, S. 398](http://books.google.com/books?id=O-ANAQAAMAAJ&ots=VI_n99OFnY&vq=ist%20unser&dq=%22ist%20unser%22%20pr%C3%A4dicat&hl=de&pg=PA398#v=snippet&q=%22ist%20unser%22&f=false). Diese unflektierte Nutzung ist aber wohl nur noch in tradierten Wendungen und Phrasen zulässig, wie im Ausgangsbeispiel (oder auch „mein und dein“ statt „meines und deines“); oder wenn gezielt ein bestimmter, altertümlich-erhabener Effekt erzielt werden soll. Dieser Effekt wird im Zitat noch dadurch verstärkt, dass nicht nur „Der Sieg ist unser“ formuliert wird, sondern bildhaft von der „Palme des Sieges“ gesprochen wird. Nach diesen Worten ist der angedeutete Rückschlag für Donald um so herber.

Die Nachweise bei Grimm sprechen übrigens deutlich gegen eine bloße Übernahme von « *La victoire est à nous !* ».

Comment: Ja,  "der Sieg ist unser" ist tatsächlich eine feststehende Phrase, ganz einverstanden. Aber Donald sagt "die  Palme (...) ist unser".Warum nicht "unsere"?

Comment: @Georges: ich habe noch ein paar Links und Ausführungen ergänzt. Die erklären zwar nicht, warum „unser“ hier nicht flektiert wird, aber sie stellen den Kontext dar und liefern weitere Beispiele für einen solchen Gebrauch des Possesivpronomens.

Comment: +1 Ich denke, Erika Fuchs wußte genau, was sie da tat. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erika_Fuchs

Comment: Danke vielmals für deine sehr interessante Ergänzung, tohuwawohu.   Es ist unglaublich, wie reich dieses Grimmsche Wörterbuch ist, wenn man denkt, dass es "mit der Hand" zusammengestellt wurde, ohne jede Computer Hilfe!

Comment: @starblue: ich bin dir für diesen ganz unerwarteten Link sehr dankbar. Da habe ich erfahren, dass es die Donaldistik gibt: tolle Wissenschaft!

Answer (score 2):

Vielleicht als kleine Hilfe oder Eselsbrücke zum Verständnis:

Was hier weggelassen wurde ist "Besitz"

> Der Sieg ist unser (Besitz)

oder

> Die Palme ist mein (Besitz)